# how to change direction and alignment of paragraph to rtl by aspsoe.word for c#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

I change alignment of paragraph to right align but when I change direction of paragraph to right to left(by `builder.ParagraphFormat.Bidi= true`) my alignment alter to left align.

```
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
builder.Font.Bidi=true;
builder.Font.LocaleIdBi = 1025;
builder.ParagraphFormat.Bidi= true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chnaged

`builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;`

to

`builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left`

and worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the alignment to after the Bidi statement?

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

// Signal to Microsoft Word that this run of text contains right-to-left text.
builder.Font.Bidi = true;
builder.CurrentParagraph.ParagraphFormat.Bidi = true;

builder.Font.LocaleIdBi = 1025;

// Insert some Arabic text.
builder.Writeln("هذا كتاب.");

doc.Save("D:\\Temp\\17.11.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.